# Public methods outside of an interface in a class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, tdd

Example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool DoSomething();
}

public class Foo:IFoo
{
    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        var result = DoOtherThing();
        ...
        return result;
    }

    public bool DoOtherThing()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My normal TDD approach would be to write unit tests on both the `DoSomething()` and `DoOtherThing()` methods. But this would be very hard to do if `DoOtherThing` was a private method. I have also read that testing private methods is a no-no.

Is it considered acceptable to have public methods on a class in order to facilitate code coverage and testing, even if the purpose of the class is only to be accessed through its (IFoo) interface? Normally I would put methods that are outside of the scope of the interface as private methods, but this does not allow you to efficiently test all of your code. Making the method public allows you to right tests on the `Foo` class, but it doesn't seem correct, at least to me, to have public methods that aren't called from outside the class. Is this way considered best for TDD or is there a better way?

Comment: If you have private method that are never called by public methods (directly or indirectly), why not just remove that code?

Comment: No I'm saying the way I used to write code, everything that wasn't a method defined on the interface i put as a private method. But when you are trying to make each method have a single responsibility, you end up with the bulk of your code in these private methods. Which are by definition not part of the public interface and as far as I have read, not necessary to be tested.

Comment: an addendum to @dbt's comment: test your private code though the public-facing methods that call them.

Comment: Another angle on @dbt's comment, as well: I've seen a lot of people asking how to cover private members. If there is no way to "use" the class within which they are defined such that they are accessed, what is their purpose? _Tests should be written to use your classes as they are **really** used._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Public methods are public because they should be accessible. Make it private if it's not intended to be invoked from the outside.

If you fail to get code coverage you might want to break up your class into multiple classes and use composition instead.

Things that are hard to test usually indicates a design flaw.

**Update**

> ok, so lets say you have a method for sending an email. Step 1 is generating a MailMessage class and populating it. Step 2 is sending the email

Thats two responsibilites (SRP). Composing an email and actually send it. I would not do that in the same class. It will also be code duplication if all your email classes  compose their messages and then send them. How do you handle network failure? Do you duplicate those checks too?

Do something like:

```
public class SendWelcomeEmailComposer
{
    MailMessage Compose(User user)
}

public class EmailSender
{
    void SendEmail(MailMessage);
}

public class EmailService
{
    void SendWelcomeEmail(User user)
    {
        // compose email
        // and send using the classes above.
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

The reason to why you should not test private methods is as far as I concern a quality measure. It's likely that you are breaking some fundamental principles (SOLID) if you get low test coverage.

So it's better to take time and reflect over the class design instead of trying to test private methods.

Comment: ok, so lets say you have a method for sending an email. Step 1 is generating a MailMessage class and populating it. Step 2 is sending the email. Your public interface has a method called SendEmail that just takes the data to send. How are you supposed to test the creation of the mailmessage and sending the mail message if both are in private methods? If you put them both in the SendEmail method directly you also can't test them individually. I'm just having a hard time seeing how to test the implementation if its not all public

Comment: My brain must just have a tendency to like procedural code over OOP then because my gut reaction to that is "having a class with a single method for every individual operation seems like a way to bloat your code in a hurry". I understand what you are getting at though.

Comment: Not every single operation. Composing something is very different from distributing them. Composition may involve using a template engine, parse text etc while the sending involves network classes.

Comment: I also think it's because the S in SOLID to me means a TASK instead of an operation. So my EmailService in your example would be in charge of all the pieces to send an email. If all of my "email classes" are in reality just this EmailService, then putting the composition method in another class just to make it testable seems like it will add code bloat. In situations where there may be a future need to extend, then yes I get what you are saying. But why do this if there is only 1 instance where this EmailService functionality is necessary?

Comment: So the task is "Compose and send emails"? Notice the "and". Not very solid. SOLID do produce smaller classes. That in turn makes them easier to reuse AND to test. In this case, the composition enables you to test the previously private methods since they are public in the new classes (since they are part of that interface)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16376/discussion-between-matt-phillips-and-jgauffin)

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to use

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NameOfYourTestAssembly")]
```

in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

This allows you to make your testable methods internal, which means they are only accessible in the assembly you are writing, AND the assemblies in this attribute.

(If you have a Mycode.dll and a Mycode.Tests.dll then you add the attribute to MyCode/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs)

Comment: Ok, so I can try this for .net code. But what about a language that doesn't have a trick like this to make the internals accessible if they are private? I think my issue is i don't see how to design the class to have methods with a single responsibility without putting all the implementation in public facing methods

Comment: Kinda, i used C# as my example. But I guess I can see this being applicable to any OOP language.

Comment: The point is that since you are usign an interface, that is the part that should be considered to be public to all consuming code. Consumers of that interface wouldn't know if they are getting a BarFoo or a FooFoo, so even with public methods, you can still mark the methods as not for public consumption (Pick a class in your favourite System.* library for examples)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concentrate on *what* to test and you'll see that the issue of *how* to design an object (or objects) that pass the tests is only a matter of preference and convenience. There is no one right answer to your problem.

Since you decided to break up your global operation in 2 steps, here's what you need to test :

1. Verify that the first part (`DoSomething()`) behaves as expected. This might include testing if it calls the right dependencies, places the Foo object in the right state, etc.
2. Verify that the first step is followed by the second one, in other words that `DoSomething()` calls `DoOtherThing()`, if needed with the right parameters.
3. Verify that the second step (`DoOtherThing()`) behaves as expected. Again, this might include it talking to its dependencies correctly, producing the right output, and so on.

No on to the *how*. While #1 is quite straightforward to test and implement since we have the prerequisite that `DoSomething()` is public, #2 and #3 leave your implementation and testing options much more open. There are basically 2 things you could do :

- Leave the 2 responsibilities in a single class. This option in turn breaks down in many possibilities : making `DoOtherThing()` *public* (easy to test but not safe, as we might not want to expose the internal substeps of the operation to the outside), making it *internal* as @AlSki points out, making it *[protected](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/mocking-protected-members-with-moq/) virtual* and using a [partial mock](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/09/the-joy-of-moq-partial-mocks/) in your test to the verify the collaboration between the 2 methods. The list certainly goes on.
- Give each step its own class. This is especially relevant if they are really 2 distinct responsibilities dealing with different parts of the system or talking to different layers. Your usual mocking and collaboration testing applies here.

**Side note 1** : Should you have failed to distinguish between the 2 responsibilities in the operation and kept the two steps together in a single method, things would have been quite different since your test would have really been an integration test instead of a unit test. This can pose some problems, like only concentrating on what happens at each end of the pipe and failing to verify the correctness of all intermediate jobs. As a consequence, I think it is always better to break up large operations in as many sensible steps as possible (like in the email sending example where creating the right `MailMessage` data structure is clearly a different responsibility than sending it) and test each one of them.

**Side note 2** : The fact that your class implements IFoo is only remotely related to all this. It basically affects the other side of the coin - defining the entry point to your class from other classes. If you want to test things in isolation, you'll probably have to create IFoo mocks in IFoo consumers' tests and verify that these consumer classes call `DoSomething()` properly.

Comment: I see your line of thinking; however, if the scope of using `DoOtherThing()` is only ever going to be called from the Foo class, then breaking it out just to be able to test it and make it a public method, then that to me seems like an unnecessary addition of complexity.

Comment: Well that seems to point towards an internal or protected DoOtherThing() then.